# Lync 2013 user setup

Tags: user-management, lync-2013

Couple simple questions on Lync Server 2013.  We have setup a standard edition environment for a single domain.  The domain is not the same the email address domain (e.g.: domain is something like domain.local, and email address are @company.com)

1. Do usernames have to be of the form username@domain.local?  Can the user logins be as simple as the standard username with out the domain?
2. Does each Lync enabled user have be to added one-by-one onto the server or can is there a way to add a global group (or distribution list) to Lync Server to simply enrollment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) lync connects to the domain after @ so that is needed.

2) this might be helpfull http://hseminiano.blogspot.dk/2013/03/lync-powershell-script-to-mass-enable.html

or see this link example 3 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398711.aspx

Comment: For (1), I suppose there is a group policy that could have the username field pre-populated to make the user's life easier?